# Kernel configuration: how to enable all modules while keeping an oldconfig

Tags: kernel, configuration

Here is my problem: I would like to configure the kernel with some specific options already set/unset by me, and then defaulting all the other options as if using `make allmodconfig`.

At the moment, I prepared a `.config` file with just the basic options I want to be set/unset. Then, I know I can issue a `make olddefconfig`, which results in a working kernel config where all the other options are answered with "default" values, but this means that most of the optional drivers are left out and not selected, not even as module.
During production, it's not rare to find out that the kernel built in this way is missing some very basic driver module (e.g. USB-serial adapter) which would be otherwise a "standard" component in a regular distro.

On the other end, if I issue a `make allmodconfig` this creates a new `.config` which disregards completely my previous assumptions, and thus is not suitable for me. Editing this `.config` by hand with `make menuconfig` for setting/unsetting the options I care is not an easy task because I ran in a loop of dependencies that I can't untangle.

Bottom line: is there a way to achieve the same of a (not existing) `make oldmodconfig` ?

Thank you...